# Ajax success code not loading in synchronous manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring-mvc

We are expecting the below things:
   Would like to show the page with updated values.
   Then show the session attribute.

What is happening for the below code, session message displayed first and then the page is getting reload.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "startSelectedServer", 
            data: { selectedJvmHostIp : selectedJvmHostIp, selectedJvmPort : selectedJvmPort },                
            success: function(result){
                1.   location.reload();
                2.   $("#save-message-div").show(); 

            },
            error : function(e) {

            }
        });

<div id="save-message-div" style="background-color: #DFF2BF; padding: 8px;display:none">
            <h2 id="save-message" style="color: #4F8A10"></h2>
        </div>
```

But we are expecting to show message after reloading the page.

In above 2 is executing first then 1 is executing.

Comment: Reload and show execute at the same time. Show doesn't wait for reload to finish so it shows the div while your page is working on reloading. Also, if you want to show a div on the current page as it is being reloaded you need add logic into the page's code when it is loading to show the div if needed as ones your page has been reloaded the JavaScript on it is also.

Answer (score 0):

ok it appears to me that you are trying to perform a server-side functionality and then refresh the page and have a message appear that the functionality has occurred.

This is fine as far as it goes but will not work the way you have it.  To do it closest to the way you invision you will want to put in conditional logic on page load to determine if it is appropriate to show the `div`.

Even if your page did not show the div prior to reloading, the way it is written, when the page reloads it will not still be executing the same piece of script - it is a blank slate with only what you pass to it.

I am not sure why you want to reload the page at all actually; you can, and should [to make use of ajax], just use the information client-side that is returned from the server asynchronously.